# calling a successful ajax post function doesn't return any data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .post

I'm trying to pass data from a form via ajax to a backend php script to interact with a database. Running the verifyUN function works, it checks to see that no similar user exists and moves on to the next function, create. Unfortunately, that create function doesn't get anything passed back to it from the php script it's calling. Does running two different $.post functions not work? Is there something simple I'm missing?

```
    function verifyUN(username,password) {
        $.post('verify.php', { login: username}, function(result) {
                console.log("passed from ajax to verify, returned: "+ result);
                if (result==0) {
                    create(username,password);
                }
                else if(result == 1) {
                    alert("Username already exists!"); //until a better error
                }
                else {
                    alert("Error:" +result);
                }
        });

    }
```

This function, create, doesn't print any returned data. Even if I paste the innards of vertifyUN making it do the same exact thing as verifyUN. It still touches the database successfully however, given the data it's passing, and even inserts the data into the database. Just nothing gets returned showing it's successful...

```
    function create(username,password){
        console.log("This is inside create function");
        $.post('create.php', { login: username, password: password}, function(returned) {
                console.log("passed from create.php to verify, returned: "+ returned);

        });
    }
```

verify.php code, which runs successfully via verifyUN.

```
//needs cleaned
require '../database/info.php';

$dbname = "test";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if($conn->connect_error) {

    die("connection not created: ". $conn->connect_error);

}

$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['login']);

if($query = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM User WHERE username = ?") ) { 

    $query->bind_param("s", $username);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($un);

    $query->fetch();
    $query->close();
    if ( $username != $un ) { //double checking

        $result = 0; //doesn't exist, sends to ajax

    }
    else {
        $result =1; //username exists, sends to ajax
    }

    echo json_encode($result);

}
else {
    echo "query failed\n";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

create.php if needed

```
require '../database/info.php';

$dbname = "test";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if($conn->connect_error) {

    die("connection not created: ". $conn->connect_error);

}

// if (!isset($_POST['login'])) {
//  $_POST['login'] = "testing";
// }
// if (!isset($_POST['password'])) {
//  $_POST['password'] = "password";
// }

$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['login']);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
$result = 0;
//echo "first result: $result\n";
$q1 = "INSERT INTO User (username) VALUES (?)";
$q2 = "INSERT INTO Security (username, shpassword) VALUES (?, ?)";

if( $stmt = $conn->prepare($q1) ) { 

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    $result++;

}
else {
    $result = 0;

    echo json_encode("Username failed\n");
}

if ( $stmt = $conn->prepare($q2) ) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    $result++;

}
else {
    echo json_encode("Failed to add user and password to database");
}

echo json_encode($result);

$conn->close();

?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create.php is using `$un` and `$hash`, but I'm not seeing those getting set anywhere.

Comment: @ChrisG fixed that, was trying to make it match verify.php as much as possible, didn't work either way given that I tested the same exact code as verifyUN though

Comment: My advice is to test your PHP code without AJAX, by creating a simple `<form method="post">`. Once your PHP code works, move on to AJAX. Beginners keep doing both at once, make typos or other simple mistakes then get stuck and waste everybody's time. (no offense)

Comment: that's why that if (!isset) is there, setting the post variables and testing from there. works successfully when running just create.php file. it's commented out when I brought in the other file/ajax

Comment: Ok, then add error handling to create()'s `$.post`

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies, I believe, in the php script `create.php` and more than likely lies with the non-declaration of the variables `$un` and `$hash`

The two sql statements are related so use the return value of the `prepare` method to either continue processing or abandon completely - the real code should/will do that more cleanly than what is shown below but you should get the idea

```
<?php

    $result = false;
    $username = !empty( $_POST['login'] ) ? $_POST['login'] : false;
    $password = !empty( $_POST['password'] ) ? $_POST['password'] : false;

    if( !$username or !$password )exit('bad foo');

    require '../database/info.php';

    $dbname = "test";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if($conn->connect_error) die("connection not created: ". $conn->connect_error);




    $q1 = "insert into `user` ( `username` ) values (?)";
    $q2 = "insert into `security` ( `username`, `shpassword` ) values (?, ?)";

    $stmt=$conn->prepare( $q1 );
    if( $stmt ) {

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        $stmt = $conn->prepare( $q2 );
        if( $stmt ){

            /* assumed algorithm here is default */
            $hash=password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT );

            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $hash );
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        } else {
            exit('all is lost-abandon ship');
        }
        $conn->close();
    } else {
        exit('prepare failed');
    }
?>
```